# Find the eigenvector for an operator on a linear span

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V$ be the linear span of the functions $1,cos(x),sin(x)$.  Let the operator $T$ on $V$ be given by the rule $Ty(x)=y(x+ \pi/4)$.  Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of T in V.

I know how to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a matrix, but I do not know how to find them in this situation.

Comment: A start would be to find the matrix of $T$,  by expressing $T(1), T(\cos)$ and $T(\sin)$ in terms of $1, \cos$ and$ \sin$. Then just find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors and 'translate' them back into your functions.

Comment: That is part of the problem.  I have no idea how to find a matrix of $T$.

Comment: For example, $T(\cos(x)) = \cos(x+\frac{\pi}{4}) = 0\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot \cos(x) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \sin(x) $, thus this could make the second column of your matrix $(0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^T $

Comment: Where did you get $0\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot \cos(x) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \sin(x)$ from?  I don't see how that relates to $T(\cos(x)) = \cos(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$

Comment: I applied $\cos(a + b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) -  \sin(a) \sin(b)$ to $\cos(x + \frac{\pi}{4})$, which is basic trigonometry.

Comment: Yeah, I see that.  I just don't understand where you got the $0 \cdot 1$ from

Comment: It just clicked.  I see where the 0 comes from.

Comment: Great! If you get a full answer, please post it as an answer to your own question!